# Spark write is taking long for data frame that has high number of columns

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a spark DataFrame with shape

```py
df.shape (380,490)
```

When I am writing to s3 its gets really slow.

```py
df.write.parquet(
        shapes_output_path,
        mode="overwrite"
)
```

I am using in default spark configurations on databricks. I did some experiment `coalesce(10)` but that did not help me.

Cluster info:

```
RUNTIME: 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)
DRIVER TYPE: c5a.8xlarge (64GB Memory, 32 Cores)
WORKER TYPE: c5a.4xlarge (32GB Memory, 16 Cores)
(Min worker 1, Max Workers 5)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide more information please? Type of cluster, Spark UI, Query Plan etc.

Comment: As parquet is a columnar file format, it is expected behavior that writing wider tables takes a longer time than the row-oriented (Avro) file format.

Comment: @Narsireddy is there a way i could make to a faster? some spark configuration that i can experiment with?

Comment: Did you tried persisting/caching the dataframe just before writing it?

Comment: @Subash about caching, as cache() is a lazy process too so it will only cache it when i do the write, i am not sure how is it going to work?

Comment: If your spark version is 3 or above you can mimic the write operation without actually writing.df.write.format(“noop”).mode(“overwrite”).save().Please perform the tuning parameters of spark